# The inverse of $A+O(N^{-1})$

Tags: inverse

Assume $A$ is invertible and I want to calculate $(A+O(N^{-1}))^{-1}$

I want to know if there exist any formula for it?

$O(N^{-1})$ is the big $O$ notation. That is the inverse of an invertible matrix $A$ plus some matrix which converge to $0$ as $N$ tends to infinity.

Is the following equality true? $$(A+O(N^{-1}))^{-1} = A^{-1}+O(N^{-1})?$$

Comment: What is $O$ (the big $O$-notation)? What is $N$?

Comment: whats A and $O(N^{-1})$ clarify your question ?

Comment: Yes, the big O notation. That is the inverse of an invertible matrix A plus some matrix which converge to 0 as N trend to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the von Neumann series, see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: Is the following equality true? (A+O(N^-1))^-1=A^-1+O(N^-1)

Comment: Neumann is not von Neumann here.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an invertible matrix, then so is $A + B = A (I + A^{-1} B)$ when 
$\|B\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, and $(A + B)^{-1} = (I + A^{-1} B)^{-1} A^{-1} = 
A^{-1} - A^{-1} B A^{-1} + \ldots$.  In particular, $\|(A+B)^{-1} - A^{-1}\| 
\le \dfrac{\|A^{-1}\|^2 \|B\|}{1 - \|A^{-1}\| \|B\|}$, 
which you can write as $(A + O(N^{-1}))^{-1} = A^{-1} + O(N^{-1})$.

Comment: many thanks! Could you give me a reference about the second equality of the second line?

Comment: See Nils's answer.

Comment: OK, I will check. Thank you for your help